# Pytorch's Equivalent of keras train_on_batch()

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

```
 acc_loss = model.train_on_batch([support, smask, query], qmask)
```

This is a part of code that I want to convert to pytorch but I'm stuck to find out if there's any Pytorch's function as `train_on_batch()` or any custom function in Pytorch that can serve the purpose.

```
support,smask,query,qmask ## these are all rank-4 tensors having (batch_size,channel,height,width)
```

The model is a custom vgg16 encoder and a decoder for segmentation.